# Processing multiple message in parallel with ActiveMQ

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'd like to process messages in a queue in parallel using a simple Processor/AsyncProcessor as a destination. The processor takes a little time per message, but each message can be handled seperately, and thus at the same time (within healthy boundaries).

I'm having a hard time finding examples, especially about the xml configuration of camel routes.

So far, I've defined a threadpool, route and processor:

```
<threadPool id="smallPool" threadName="MyProcessorThread" poolSize="5" maxPoolSize="50" maxQueueSize="100"/>
<route>
    <from uri="broker:queue:inbox" />
    <threads executorServiceRef="smallPool">
        <to uri="MyProcessor" />
    </threads>
</route>
<bean id="MyProcessor" class="com.example.java.MyProcessor" />
```

and my processor looks like:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        String msg = in.getBody(String.class);      
        System.out.println(msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); // Do something in the background
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly, when I post messages to the queue, they are still processed one by one, each delayed by 10 seconds (my "background task").

Can anyone point me to the right direction to have the messages processed using the defined threadpool or explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried concurrentConsumers? In your example that would be broker:queue:inbox?concurrentConsumers=5 (or whatever).  I don't recall if each consumer thread will use its own instance of the processor or not, but unless you start a new thread in the processor you will need multiple anyway as the route has to complete before the "from" is invoked again.

Comment: Have you looked at the Camel Load Balancer? http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html

Comment: @Fortyrunner I think load-balancer will be for and outbound or to endpoint . In this case concurrent consumer will do the magic.

Comment: One trick I use is to setup a number of SEDA queues and load balance the input queue onto those SEDA queues. SEDA itself runs on separate threads. Maybe I should look at concurrentConsumers. There is more than one way to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the concurrentConsumers options as said in the comments,

```
<route>
    <from uri="broker:queue:inbox?concurrentConsumers=5" />
    <to uri="MyProcessor" />
</route>
```

Notice there is also `maxConcurrentConsumers` you can set to use a min/max range of concurrent consumers, so Camel will automatic grow/shrink depending on load.

See more details in the JMS docs at

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: is there a way to change `concurrentConsumers` property dynamically in runtime? Camel offer such capability? A way to increase or decrease the number of consumers in runtime. Maybe via JMX or HawtIO mgtm console.

Comment: Do we any way to make changes dynamically to `concurrentConcumers`? @Tuelho Have you got any solution?

Comment: You can change it using JMX / from the hawtio web console

Comment: I am reading from an s3 bucket -> splitting based on a token -> streaming -> parallelProcessing(). I am not specifying any threads, however, it looks like it is processing my sub messages in parallel. Am I interpreting it correctly? Camel v2.19.1. Thanks in advance!