# Losing messages in processors on broker restart

Tags: activemq-classic, processor

In my [previous message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674072/processing-multiple-message-in-parallel-with-activemq) I was looking for a solution to handle incoming messages in parallel. After a lot of trial and error, I think I might have a working solution.

However, one of the requirements of the platform I'm working on, is that messages that are being processed need to be "restarted" or "re-queued" in case of an abrupt broker restart.

While testing, I have succesfully started several processors at once to perform a unit-of-work per message. What I found when abruptly restarting the broker, is that any message being "worked on" inside a processor is actually lost. However, when the processor throws a deliberate exception, the message is redelivered to the queue.

How can I safeguard my message while it's being processed (and the unit-of-work has not finished)?
Any advise is highly appreciated.

Note: the final implementation will be using a master-master setup of two identical brokers behind a tcp load-balancer.

Comment: Are you using transactions and are the messages in question persistent?

Comment: the messages are posted to a queue with DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT. Not sure how I would add transactions to my processors. Currently, all "in-flight" messages are gone if I kill the java process for activemq.

Comment: I just added transactions to each route, but then messages no longer get processed in parallel...

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve your message you must use transactions with persistent messaging.  Without transacted sessions not all exception scenarios are covered, especially if you are using the default AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, which tells the broker you have consumed the message, so go a head and delete it as soon as the message has been delivered.  That is why when you restart the broker you lose your message. There is no other way around this.

Assuming you have transactions set up properly, then there is no reason you should not be able to process in parallel. [This blog is a bit older now](http://tmielke.blogspot.com/2012/03/camel-jms-with-transactions-lessons.html), but still full of good information to be sure you are setting up your transactions properly.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this doesn't work as expected, especially when doing things in tandem using the AsyncProcessor interface. From http://camel.apache.org/jms.html I read that setting asyncConsumer=true is ignored once you set transacted=true. I might get support for async transactions in Camel 3.0 :(

Comment: That is a separate issue. In response to your question here, the only option to ensure messages are fully processed before the broker deletes them is to use transactions.

Comment: Can't you use `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` to ensure at-least-once delivery of all messages?  You'll get redelivery on a broker restart instead of non-delivery, but if the consumer can handle that, you'd avoid losing messages...

Comment: Its possible things have changed, but was under the impression that this would not protect the message throughout the route (ie if the route goes down ungracefully)

Comment: As I understood it, it protects against non-delivery, by allowing redelivery.  So if the route goes down and you haven't yet acked the message but have processed it, you might get it again and you have to be OK with that risk.  But I haven't dealt with acknowledgement options in years so I might be wrong about how it works.

Comment: So under normal circumstances, that is correct, but with camel and asyncConsumer=true as he is using, I believe the client ack comes once the exchange is handed to the processor. Therefore, anything in-flight being processed would potentially be lost.